# Laravel REST Resource can't post to API

Tags: php, rest, laravel, curl, laravel-5

I've built a REST API in Laravel, it's currently running locally using MAMP although I have tried it out on a live server and the same issue crops up.

When I try to post my form to the API it doesn't work unless I simultaneously have Artisan serve the site on a different port number and post to that URL i.e www.mysite.com:2834/api/courses, I can GET the page in a browser no problem, it's just POST'ing that causes an issue.

I have CORs enabled and I have tried to do the same POST request using PostMan and it gives the same results i.e does not work when it's just the normal URL www.mysite.com/api/courses that I post to but works when I also run Artisan on a different port and post to www.mysite.com:2834/api/courses.

Oddly enough the POST works without Artisan running when done using CURL:

```
         curl -i -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://www.mysite.io/api/courses  --data "&author=tertertert&name=ertertert&description=ertertret&price=ertretret"
```

Here is my routes list :

```
            |        | GET|HEAD                       | api/courses                                            | api.courses.index    | App\Http\Controllers\CourseController@index                | web,cors                                        |
            |        | POST                           | api/courses                                            | api.courses.store    | App\Http\Controllers\CourseController@store                | web,cors                                        |
            |        | GET|HEAD                       | api/courses/{courses}                                  | api.courses.show     | App\Http\Controllers\CourseController@show                 | web,cors                                        |
            |        | PUT|PATCH                      | api/courses/{courses}                                  | api.courses.update   | App\Http\Controllers\CourseController@update               | web,cors                                        |
            |        | DELETE                         | api/courses/{courses}                                  | api.courses.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\CourseController@destroy              | web,cors                                        |
```

and my controller :

```
            <?php

            namespace App\Http\Controllers;

            use App\Course;
            use App\Http\Requests;
            use App\Http\Requests\CourseForm;


            class CourseController extends Controller
            {
                /**
                 * Display a listing of the resource.
                 *
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
                public function index()
                {
                    $courses = Course::all();
                    return response()->json(['courses' => $courses]);
                }

                /**
                 * @param CourseForm $request
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
                 */
                public function store(CourseForm $request)
                {
                        $course = new Course();
                        $course->author = $request->input('author');
                        $course->name = $request->input('name');
                        $course->description = $request->input('description');
                        $course->price = $request->input('price');
                        $course->save();
                        return response()->json(['message' => 'Course saved']);

                }

                /**
                 * Display the specified resource.
                 *
                 * @param  int  $id
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
                public function show($id)
                {
                    $course = Course::find($id);
                    return response()->json(['course' => $course]);
                }

                /**
                 * Update the specified resource in storage.
                 *
                 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
                 * @param  int  $id
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
                public function update(CourseForm $request, $id)
                {
                    if($request->ajax())
                    {
                        $course = Course::find($id);
                        $course->author = $request->input('author');
                        $course->name = $request->input('name');
                        $course->description = $request->input('description');
                        $course->price = $request->input('price');
                        $course->save();
                        return response()->json(['message' => 'Course updated']);
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
                 *
                 * @param  int  $id
                 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
                 */
                public function destroy($id)
                {
                    $course = Course::find($id);
                    $course->delete();
                    return response()->json(['message' => 'Course removed']);
                }
            }
```

and my routes file:

```
            <?php

            Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['cors']], function(){
                Route::resource('courses', 'CourseController', ['except' => [
                    'create', 'edit'
                ]]);
            });

            Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['cors']], function(){

                Route::resource('test', 'HomepageController@index');
                Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController@index');
            });



            Route::controllers([
                'auth'     => 'Auth\AuthController',
                'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
            ]);


            Route::group(['before' => 'auth', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

            Route::get('/admin/','DashboardController@overview');



            });


                //Route::get('/test', 'HomepageController@index');
```

Comment: Does it return an error or a status code in postman?

Comment: No its really weird, when I do the POST it acts like a GET and just returns the index method of the controller so it just shows all the json for all the records

Comment: Is your app configure to using middleware cors instead of web?
web middleware includes session, csrf,, if you are using a laravel 5.2. Look at your guards in configs/auth.php

Comment: Hmmm It looks like in the routes list its using both (web,cors) check it above - Im looking to use just the cors middlewear I think, however im relatively new to laravel so il go on your advice ? This site is built using angular so the cors middlewear will be necessary

Comment: Do you get any different results if you add `X-Requested-With => XMLHttpRequest` header to your postman POST request?

Comment: Nope, thats what im using already :)

Comment: anything that's not given a web middleware will not have cookies or session or CSRF functional.

Comment: They all appear to have web and cors if you check out the output from route:list above.. i dont necessarily need cookies sessions or csrf as most of the laravel part of the app is just serving json pages from the database

Answer (score 5):

Ladies and Gentlemen in true face palm fashion Ive figured out what the hell was wrong... it was the trailing slash on the end of the url that was messing it all up..

Comment: Programming in a nutshell.

Comment: 3 hours searching for this answer